# Websphere ear deploment is failed

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear

I am trying to deploy ear file and there is error comes saying

> "A composition unit with name ace-ear already exists. Select a
>   different application name"

which is not there . what else can be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not recommended, you can manually remove the references of the ear from the server configuration files.

To check if the ear exists inside the profile, run the below command from Dmgr/config folder. Delete the ear files manually, if present.

```
find . -name '*ace-ear*'
```

To check if there are ear references in the configuration xmls, run the below command from Dmgr/config folder, and then remove those entries from the xml files manually, if present.

```
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs grep -i ace-ear
```

Post this, Restart the Deployment manager, sync nodes and restart the JVMs and try deploying the application.

**NOTE : Be very careful updating the server configuration files manually, as any mistakes can corrupt the server configurations. Taking profile backups before applying any changes to server configuration files is recommended.**

Comment: Thanks a lot @M I P

Answer (score 9):

```
1.Check the following locations to see if the application directories exist. If they do exist delete the application folder 'your_app'
<profile root>/config/cells/cellname/applications/your_app
<profile root>/config/cells/cellname/blas/your_app
<profile root>/config/cells/cellname/cus/your_app

2.Clear the contents of the profile/wstemp directory 
3.Clear the contents of the profile/temp director
4.Restart the Application Server.
```

Comment: See also https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/composition-unit-name-maximo-already-exists

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on remote environment, with ftp filezilla client searched for all occurrences of my application name inside appserver folders (Server --> Find remote files), then deleted all folder and files with the name of the application, restarted server, deploy again the application, succeeded